# Fetching data to phonope api

Tags: integration

I have fetched data to phonepe api "https://api-preprod.phonepe.com/apis/merchant-simulator/pg/v1/pay" the base 64 payload as request in body and Sha256 x-verify as x-verify in headers. When i fetch data on phonepe website postman it works and i get a transaction initiated response but It doesn't work on either localhost or on official website "wearmiho.com".
Shows error
""Access to fetch at 'https://api-preprod.phonepe.com/apis/merchant-simulator/pg/v1/pay' from origin 'https://www.wearmiho.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.""

I have tried to add mode: "no-cors" to headers but it still didn't worked shows error failed
Possible reasons
1.) Maybe it needs to have the domain name pre-register on phonepe As for example firebase requires some registered domain to have access to its functionalities I have talked to the phonepe team they said for test credentials it should work on any url like localhost or live website
2.) Maybe my code got some error but its the same as on phonepe postman ref "https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/reference/pay-api#pay-request-for-web-flow"(the side postman ALso i used js)

Comment: The exact issue I am facing now. Did you fix the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using PhonePe API on the client side you have to use PhonePe API on the server side in your backend.